# DocumentDB - Does a newer session token guarantee reading back older writes?

Tags: session, azure-cosmosdb

Let's assume I have two documents in the same collection/partition, both at "version 1": `A1`, `B1`.

I update `A1` -> `A2`, the write operation returns a session token `SA`.
Using `SA` to read document `A` will guarantee I get version `A2`.

Now I update `B1` -> `B2`, and get a new session token `SB`.
Using `SB` to read document `B` will guarantee I get version `B2`.

My question is:
does using token `SB` guarantee I can see *older* writes as well?
I.e. will reading `A` with token `SB` always get me `A2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your case SB > SA and hence it will ensure latest version of A.

Comment: Can you explain which consistency model guarantees this?  
Using session consistency, all reads are current with writes from that session, but writes from other sessions may lag. 
SA and SB are different sessions